# Check if method return any value type int

Tags: java

I have method that return value of int and I want to check if the method return any value 
how I can do that?

I have tried to do like below with greater than but I'm not sure that this is the right way
since I'm checking for specific `> 0` but not if the method return any value.

```
if (Type.FixedLength() > 0)  {

    //do something...

}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 6):

An `int` is a primitive data type, so the function would have to return an `int`, it can't return `null` and thus will always return a "value".

A standard way to return a non-result or error condition would be to use something far out of the typical range of expected results such as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` when an expected result would be positive.

It is also recommended to only start `class` names with capital letters, thus a better name for your function would be `Type.fixedLength()`.

Answer (score 5):

A method that returns an `int` will always return a value, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Well...it could throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A method can do three basic things: return, throw an Exception or block the program. A method with a declared return type returns always a value of that type.
So if your code compiles and your progam exits with no Exceptions the Method will return a value.

There are two easy ways to find out if a method returns the expected value.

1. store the value in a variable and print that variable to the console before the if statement. Like this:

   int fixedLength = Type.FiixedLength();
   System.out.println(fixedLength);
   if(fixedLength > 0){
      //code
   }
2. use the debugger.

Comment: How is blocking returning if it's blocked?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an data type before your method, which means it will always return a value, int in this case. However, since your question looking for a check of value returned, you could use:

```
System.out.printf("Returned value is: %d", Type.fixedLength());
```

This is a way to see the returned value any way.

Hope it helps